# Linux Kernel makefile process explained

Tags: linux, makefile, build, linux-kernel

In LinuxSrc/Documentation/admin-guide/README.rst under the section for building the kernel exists these 4 steps, can someone explain what each one does?
Is it similiar to a ./configure, ./make, ./install?

**To configure and build the kernel, use:**

```
1.) cd /usr/src/linux-4.X
2.) make O=/home/name/build/kernel menuconfig 
3.) make O=/home/name/build/kernel
4.) sudo make O=/home/name/build/kernel modules_install install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) simple cd - no explanation needed

2) Running `make menuconfig` starts an ncurses-based text mode kernel configuration tool.

3) `make O=/home/name/build/kernel` configures and builds the kernel.

4.1) `modules_install`: This will copy the compiled modules into /lib/modules/-.

4.2) `install`: This command will copy following files into /boot directory (and might do more depending on the distribution):
Config-*, System.map-*, Vmlinuz-*

`vmlinuz` - Is a compressed Linux kernel

`system.map` -  Is a lookup table between symbol names and their addresses in memory for a particular build of a kernel

`config` - The kernel configuration created by the `make menuconfig`

Comment: Thank you, can you explain those 3 files being sent to the /boot dir?